# PHP Regex to get img inside WP Caption

Tags: php, regex, caption

I want to get the img tag inside the caption tag

Example:

```
[caption id="attachment_5433" align="aligncenter" width="413"]
    <a href="abc.jpg"><img class=" wp-image-5433" title="This is a title" src="abc.jpg" alt="This is alt" width="413" height="551"></a>This is a desc
[/caption]
```

and the result:

```
<img class=" wp-image-5433" title="This is a title" src="abc.jpg" alt="This is alt" width="413" height="551">
```

How to do it by PHP regex?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: `/\[caption.*?].*?(<img.*?\/?>).*?\[/caption]/` ish~ (http://regexr.com?34iqr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $string = '[caption id="attachment_5433" align="aligncenter" width="413"]
    <a href="abc.jpg"><img class=" wp-image-5433" title="This is a title" src="abc.jpg" alt="This is alt" width="413" height="551"></a>This is a desc
[/caption]';

    $result = preg_match_all("/\[caption.*?].*?(<img.*?\/?>).*?\[\/caption]/s", $string, $matches);

    print_r($matches);
?>
```

**Ouput**

```
Array
(
    [0] : Array
        (
            [0] : '[caption id="attachment_5433" align="aligncenter" width="413"]
    <a href="abc.jpg"><img class=" wp-image-5433" title="This is a title" src="abc.jpg" alt="This is alt" width="413" height="551"></a>This is a desc
[/caption]'
        )

    [1] : Array
        (
            [0] : '<img class=" wp-image-5433" title="This is a title" src="abc.jpg" alt="This is alt" width="413" height="551">'
        )

)
```

**Update, with replace callback**

```
<?php
    $string = '[caption id="attachment_5433" align="aligncenter" width="413"]
    <a href="abc.jpg"><img class=" wp-image-5433" title="This is a title" src="abc.jpg" alt="This is alt" width="413" height="551"></a>This is a desc
[/caption]';

    echo preg_replace_callback('/\[caption.*?].*?(<img.*?\/?>).*?\[\/caption]/s', function($matches) {
        return $matches[1];
    }, $string);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Allendar. It works! By the way, I want to replace the whole string by the result (img tag). How to do it?

Comment: Added replace with callback to the answer. Happy coding :)

Comment: Allendar, how would you modify this to extract the caption text ("This is a desc") in addition to the img attribute?

Comment: Try something like this (not tested): `\[caption.*?].*?(<img.*?\/?>).*?<\/a>(.*?)\[\/caption]` It will add a new catch group to your result array.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/\[caption.*?\].*?(\<img[^>]*?).*?\[\/caption\]/', $stringWhereToSearchImg, $matches);
```

matches will have img tag.

By the way you don't have ending that for img you should end it with />

Comment: This doesn't match image tags within captions.

Comment: You still miss some extra escapes that PHP needs for RegEx. Hint; `E_WARNING : type 2 -- preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 29 -- at line 6`